# Django Rest Framework - Nested Serialization with intermediary model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have three models, one of them being an intermediary model linking the other two. I can properly nest  these two models via foreign key relation, but I would like to use this intermediary model to link them together since having direct key relation is undesirable in the situation. Desired output at the bottom.

**models.py**

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)


class Child(models.Model):
    given_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    # reverse relation works, but an intermediary model is preferred
    # parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name="parents" on_delete=models.PROTECT)


class Link(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    child = models.ForeignKey(Child, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ChildSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = '__all__'


class LinkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # what should I place here?

    class Meta:
        model = Link
        fields = '__all__'


class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    children = LinkSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'children')
```

**api_output.json**

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Appleseed",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "given_name": "Uno Appleseed"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "given_name": "Dos Appleseed"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to specify source of field using [`source`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) keyword in LinkSerializer:

```
class LinkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    given_name = serializers.CharField(source='child.given_name')
    id = given_name = serializers.CharField(source='child.id')  

    class Meta:
        model = Link
        fields = ('given_name', 'id')
```

Comment: Is it necessary to create one serializer field for each model field with this solution? I mean, is there a way similar to `children = ChildSerializer(source="*", many=True)`? It does get unwieldy when I want to show all columns.

Comment: @Nogurenn yes you need to define each field separately. As alternative you can try customize ParentSerializer with http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield